# How to copy <xml> tag inside CDATA by XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, cdata, xml-formatting

I  want to add  nodes  to  my  xml data  and  keep  CDATA  format  unchangeble   i  have xml  file  in which  i  write  xml  content  which  should  be  copied  in my  shablon xml
here  is  xml  contetn  which  should  be added  to  shablon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Data>
<RawData Format="Text">
<organizationNameEng>fgfgfg</organizationNameEng>
<organizationNameGeo>dfdfdf</organizationNameGeo>
<organizationIdentifier>123456789</organizationIdentifier>
<cardNumber>dfdfdf</cardNumber></RawData>
<response>
<id>0123</id>
<content>her  is  content</content>
</response>
</Data>

here  is  my  shablon xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><DataPrep xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Lcid="String">
<Job Name="CompleteJob" Type="Normal" Priority="1">
<JobDetails>![CDATA[ here is  job  details ]]</JobDetails>
<DetailData>
<Information>
<RawData Format="Text"><</RawData>
</Data>
<response>
...
</response>
</Information>
</DetailData>
</Job>
```

here  is  my  xlst

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="RawData"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Detaildata/information">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('content.xml')"/>
    </xsl:template>
        </xsl:copy>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which  will  give  me  response  like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><DataPrep xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Lcid="String">
<Job Name="CompleteJob" Type="Normal" Priority="1">
<JobDetails>&lt here is  job  details &gt</JobDetails>
<DetailData>
<Information>
<RawData Format="Text"><![CDATA[
<organizationName>fgfgfg</organizationNameEn>
<organizationIdentifier>123456789</organizationIdentifier>
<cardNumber>dfdfdf</cardNumber>
]]></RawData>
</Data>
</Information>
</DetailData>
</Job>
</DataPrep>
```

how   should  i change  my  xslt  file  that   i  could paste  tag  inside  ..]] and also  how  should  i  avoid situation  where  response tag  in xslt  and  doesn't  change `<CDATA>`   format  with  `&gt  &lt`  here

```
<JobDetails>&lt here is  job  details &gt</JobDetails>
```

Comment: You can't have tags inside CDATA. CDATA means "character data": it means "there may be things in here that look like tags, but they aren't really tags, they are just plain characters."

Comment: i  know  but   i  really  need   here  to  be this  <xml >